# Mapped drives are not visible for administrator in Windows 2000

Tags: windows, windows-2000

I've a laptop (without internet connection) that still runs with the good old Windows 2000.

I'm logged in with the user 'John' and I map a network drive: `net use x: \\myserver\myshare`. When I do `net use` the mapped network drive is listed: `X: \\myserver\myshare`

Now I open two administrative command prompts: `runas /u:administrator cmd` `psexec -u administrator cmd`

When I do `net use` in the administrative command prompts the mapped network drive `X:` is not listed.

I know, in Windows 7, 8 & 10 I can fix this issue by adding the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLinkedConnections` and set the value to `1`. But unfortunately this doesn't work in Windows 2000.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make mapped drives visible to all users also in Windows 2000?

Comment: Windows 2000 only uses SMBv1 and that has been turned off in all recent versions of Windows and now SMBv2 up is the installed protocol. I do not recommend enabling SMBv1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Drives are mapped to individual user sessions. You don't have access to drive maps from different user accounts in Windows

Comment: Does this mean that only SMBv2 has the feature that allows you to see in an administrative command prompt the drives you mapped with a normal user and that this is not possible with SMBv1?